# Anyone here capable of removing a launch condition from an old Win32 file having a "Sony InstallLock"?

Tags: delphi

I would like to extract the BIOS ROM file it contains, but it refuses to run. Even on the model it is intended for since I lack one or more SONY-custom DLLs on my installation. Since Sony decided to delete all old drivers from their website, I am unable to identify what Sony 3rd party thing are missing.

7zip, UniExtract, WinRAR, ResourceHacker...no luck. I could save a binary aside with ResourceHacker but it was only a WRAPPER.EXE file which is of no use. The actual ROM file is not to be found in WRAPPER.EXE.

File: http://dose.0wnz.at/ftp.vaio-link.com/PUB/VAIO/BIOS/R0232U2.EXE
(look like Borland Delphi 5/6)

Answer (score 1):

I spend a few minutes looking at this and I can give some hints to help you:

- The executable was indeed written in Delphi
- The executable has another executable (wrapper.exe) embedded as a resource (you already found this).
- The executable looks in the registry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sony Corporation\Shared Info\Shared DLLs and then for the REG_SZ value PC_INFO.DLL
- It wants the function `_pc_info2` from this dll.
- You can download software from this link: https://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=1800867 and inside the zip is Utils Installer 2 Sony Shared Library -> this contains the required dll.
- Without debugger it looks like it does some checks to see if system is a sony pc etc and errors with `Sorry, you do not have permissions to extract this package`
- If the exe detects a debugger it continues without further checks (however it errors out with `invalid archive type`
- This patent seems related: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20050240815

If you want to patch the binary to always think a debugger is attached you can make the following changes:

```
fc /b R0232U2.EXE R0232U2-p.EXE
Comparing files R0232U2.EXE and R0232U2-P.EXE
0004B368: FF 89
0004B369: 25 C0
0004B36A: C8 40
0004B36B: 67 90
0004B36C: 46 90
0004B36D: 00 90
0004B36E: 8B 90
0004B36F: C0 90
```

Here's a PowerShell script to make above patch, it assumes the original file is in the same folder as the script. It saves it as `R0232U2-patched.EXE` in the script folder.

```
function Apply-HexDiff {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$OriginalFile,
        [string]$ModifiedFile,
        [string[]]$HexDiff
    )
    
    # Read the original file into a byte array
    $originalData = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($OriginalFile)

    # Apply changes
    foreach ($line in $HexDiff) {
        $tokens = $line -split ':| '
        $address = [Convert]::ToInt32($tokens[0], 16)
        $originalByte = [Convert]::ToByte($tokens[2], 16)
        $modifiedByte = [Convert]::ToByte($tokens[3], 16)

        # Check if original byte matches before applying change
        if ($originalData[$address] -eq $originalByte) {
            $originalData[$address] = $modifiedByte
            Write-Host ("Patched {0:X2} to {1:X2} at offset {2:X}" -f $originalByte, $modifiedByte, $address)
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Byte at address $($address.ToString('X')) does not match original byte $($originalByte.ToString('X2'))"
        }
    }

    # Write the modified data back into the file
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($ModifiedFile, $originalData)
}

# Example usage:
$hexDiff = @(
    "0004B368: FF 89",
    "0004B369: 25 C0",
    "0004B36A: C8 40",
    "0004B36B: 67 90",
    "0004B36C: 46 90",
    "0004B36D: 00 90",
    "0004B36E: 8B 90",
    "0004B36F: C0 90"
)

$originalFile = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "R0232U2.EXE"
$patchedFile = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "R0232U2-patched.EXE"
Apply-HexDiff -OriginalFile $originalFile -ModifiedFile $patchedFile -HexDiff $hexDiff
```